# Set initial state on RadioGroup without entering OnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, radio-group

I am using RadioGroup and when the user presses on one on the buttons a call to the database is being made (updating data). I have set OnCheckedChangeListener for the RadioGroup:

```
viberPermissionView.getAppPermissions().setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, 
    int checkedRadioButtonId) 
    {
     callService(App.VIBER, checkedRadioButtonId);
    }
});
```

I have an issue when I am opening the application and setting the state of the buttons (which one is selected) it is the same as pressing on the button and I am making a call to the database and updating data unnecessarily. I want to avoid this call to the database to set the state without entering in method OnCheckedChangeListener. Here is the part of how I am currently setting the initial state:

```
private void createResourcePicker() {
    resourcePicker.setSlideOnFling(false);
    resourcePicker.setAdapter(new PermissionsAdapter(permissions));
    resourcePicker.addScrollStateChangeListener(this);
    resourcePicker.addOnItemChangedListener(this);
    resourcePicker.scrollToPosition(1);
    resourcePicker.setItemTransitionTimeMillis(10);
    resourcePicker.setItemTransformer(new ScaleTransformer.Builder()
            .setMinScale(0.8f)
            .build());
}
```

Comment: What about setup listener after setting value(state)? Or putting guard (`mFromSetup = true; setState(); mFromSetup = false;` and then `if(!mFromSetup)allService(App.VIBER, checkedRadioButtonId)`)?

Comment: Have you tried setting the listener after you set the initial state of the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a way to solve this issue. In the OnCheckedChanged method I am taking the RadioButton and setting a OnClickListener. In the OnClickListener I am setting the function that need to be executed when the user presses the button and it is not executed when the state of the RadioGroup is set dynamically. Here is the logic:

```
viberPermissionView.getAppPermissions().setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, 
                int checkedRadioButtonId) {
                    final RadioButton checkedButton =     
                viberPermissionView.findViewById(checkedRadioButtonId);
                    checkedButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            startService(checkedButton, 
                              App.VIBER);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```